# Having trouble drawing a tree diagram

Tags: syntax, terminology, english, syntax-trees, relative-clauses

I'm having trouble drawing a tree diagram for the following sentence:

> Chrissy believed that the earrings she bought for Sue were real silver.

In the task we have to divide the sentence into its clauses and state the types of clauses.

I choose 1 sentence and 2 clauses were Chrissy believed is already 1 clause.

Comment: I'm guessing that part of your problem is that _she bought for Sue_ is a relative clause but with the relative pronoun (eg _which_) suppressed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Answer (score 4):

[image: diagram]

Is this about what you were looking for?

Comment: That does the job. There are other angels that could dance on a more elaborately pinheaded tree, but they're not necessary.

Comment: @jlawler: There are always more angels that can simultaneously dance on the pinheaded tree; but only the invisible ones can, who don't make for good Christmas decorations.

Comment: @jlawler I replaced the original but changed the graphics to make it more readable.

Comment: @Alenanno: Great!